# MPMoviePlayerViewController disappears when player contentURL is changed

Tags: ios, cocoa, mpmediaplayercontroller

I know, there are tens of similar questions. I read them all and still could not find an answer.
I show view with video via `presentModalViewController` method. When user makes swipe, I would like next video to start in the same player. But when I try to change `contentURL` of video player, view disappears - like if `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` method was called (but it was not).

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(!moviePlayerViewController)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"];

        moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];       

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipe:)];
        leftSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [moviePlayerViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeRecognizer];

        [self presentModalViewController:moviePlayerViewController animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)leftSwipe:(id)sender
{
    moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL = 
        moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL; // no matter what exactly URL here.
    [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play]; // view disappears even before this line is reached
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange thing: I spent whole yesterday trying to find an answer in vain, and I found it one minute after posting question here.

http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/dismissing-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-the-right-way/